# Program type already present: org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am new developing Android Apps, I'm trying to run an application but I receive this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at app.unityudx.io.new_app.process.UnityApplication.onCreate(UnityApplication.java:59)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:86)
            at app.unityudx.io.new_app.process.UnityApplication.onCreate(UnityApplication.java:59) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I researched, and people in internet say that the class is not in Classpath, but when I add `implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'` in graddle this error present

```
Program type already present: org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
```

Android Studio is 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that other lib includes that lib. you need to find out which one and add :
exclude.

in my case it was:

```
implementation (group: 'io.jafka', name: 'jeos', version: '0.9.14') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```